# PYQT5 update Label in 2nd window everytime variable changes

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

So I want do display a global variable (= currenteMoney) in my second Window (= moneywindow1). It works fine, but everytime I change the value of my variable in my Mainwindow, the lable that displays the variable in my second window should update.

```
from cheatwindow import cheatwindow1
from moneywindow import moneywindow1
import globals

class MyWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__()
        self.cheatwindow1 = None
        self.moneywindow1 = None
        self.setGeometry(600, 200, 800, 600)
        self.setWindowTitle("MyMainWindow")
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        globals.global_vars()

        mainMenu = self.menuBar()
        fileMenu = mainMenu.addMenu('File')
        save = QAction('New', self)
        save.setShortcut("Ctrl+S")
        save.triggered.connect(lambda: self.clicked_menu(0))
        load = QAction('Load', self)
        load.setShortcut("Ctrl+L")
        load.triggered.connect(lambda: self.clicked_menu(1))
        fileMenu.addAction(save)
        fileMenu.addAction(load)

        specialsMenu = mainMenu.addMenu('Specials')
        cheats = QAction("cheats", self)
        cheats.setShortcut("Ctrl+C")
        cheats.triggered.connect(lambda: self.clicked_menu(2))
        specialsMenu.addAction(cheats)

# Button that if clicked changes the variable
        self.ButtonThrow = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.ButtonThrow.setText("Roll dice")
        self.ButtonThrow.move(300, 300)
        self.ButtonThrow.adjustSize()
        self.ButtonThrow.setEnabled(True)
        self.ButtonThrow.clicked.connect(lambda: self.throw_dice(0))

    def clicked_menu(self, a):
        if a == 0:
            print("Save")
        elif a == 1:
            self.money_popup()
        elif a== 2:
            self.cheat_popup()
        else:
            pass

# def that changes the variable
    def throw_dice(self, a):
        if a == 0:
            self.ButtonThrow.setEnabled(False)
            globals.currentThrow = random.randint(1, globals.diceMax)
            globals.currentMoney += globals.currentThrow*globals.diceCount
            QTimer.singleShot(globals.cdThrow*1000, lambda: 
        self.ButtonThrow.setEnabled(True))
        elif a == 1:
            pass
        self.labelWürfelpoints.setText("Letzer Wurf: " + 
               str(globals.currentThrow) + "\n" + "Gesamtpunktzahl: "+ 
               str(globals.currentMoney))
        self.labelWürfelpoints.adjustSize()

# Opens the 2.nd window
    def money_popup(self):
        if self.moneywindow1 is None:
            self.moneywindow1 = moneywindow1()
        self.moneywindow1.show()
        self.moneywindow1.activateWindow()


    def cheat_popup(self):
        if self.cheatwindow1 is None:
            self.cheatwindow1 = cheatwindow1()
        self.cheatwindow1.show()
        self.cheatwindow1.activateWindow()

def window():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = MyWindow()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

window()
```

script of my 2nd window that displays the variable:

```
import globals

class moneywindow1(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(moneywindow1, self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(800, 400, 250, 200)
        self.setWindowTitle("MONEY")
        self.setupUi()

    def setupUi(self):
        globals.global_vars()

        self.label1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.label1.setFont(font)
        self.label1.move(100, 80)
        self.label1.setText(str(globals.currentMoney))
        self.label1.adjustSize()

# def that updates the lable so the current value of the variable is displayed
    def moneywin_updater(self):
        self.label1.setText(str(globals.currentMoney))
        self.label1.adjustSize()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app2 = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win2 = moneywindow1()
    win2.show()
    sys.exit(app2.exec_())
```

The thing is, my variable (= currentMoney) can also be changed in my 3rd window (= cheatwindow1) so it would be nice to finde a general solution that is not bind to changes only done in the mainwindow. Btw the "import globals" script is here:

```
def global_vars():
    global currentMoney
    currentMoney = 0
```

Comment: Where are you changing this variable in your code? In any case, you shouldn't use global variables for this. The standard way to broadcast data to other widgets is to use signals and slots.

Comment: Okay I edited the Button and def to the script above which changes the variable. I just googled what signals and slots are and I think that is what I did in my script. Can you give me an example of what you mean ? :)  And the variable is global cause it is used in different windows and if one change it in one window it is automaticaly changed in all the other windows.(= sry am new to python this method may be inefficent).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a stripped down version of your code to illustrate what I mean. The current amount of money is stored in an instance variable of `MyWindow`. I also created a signal `MyWindow.money_changed` which is emitted every time the dice are rolled and the amount of money is changed. By connecting this signal to `self.moneywindow.moneywin_updater`, the label in the second window is updated automatically every time the dice are rolled in the first window.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
import random

class moneywindow1(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle("MONEY")
        self.move(500,500)
        self.setupUi()

    def setupUi(self):
        self.label1 = QtWidgets.QLabel('', self)
        layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.label1, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)

    def moneywin_updater(self, amount):
        self.label1.setText(f'Current amount of money is {amount}')
        self.update()
        self.show()

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    money_changed = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi()

        # create a moneywindow1 dialog and connect moneywin_updater to the signal money_changed
        self.moneywindow = moneywindow1(self)
        self.money_changed.connect(self.moneywindow.moneywin_updater)

        self.diceMax = 6
        self.currentMoney = 0

    def setupUi(self):
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel('Click button to roll dice', self)
        self.label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Roll', self)

        vlayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        vlayout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        vlayout.addWidget(self.label)
        vlayout.addWidget(self.button)

        self.button.clicked.connect(self.throw_dice)

    def throw_dice(self, a):
        currentThrow = random.randint(1, self.diceMax)
        self.currentMoney += currentThrow
        self.label.setText(f"Letzer Wurf: {currentThrow}\nGesamtpunktzahl: {self.currentMoney}")
        self.money_changed.emit(self.currentMoney)
        if not self.moneywindow.isVisible():
            self.moneywindow.show()


if __name__ == "__main__" :
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    win = MyWindow()
    win.show()
    app.exec()
```

Comment: Hmm I am not sure if this is to much to ask, but can you explain to my why the script knows, that "amount" in moneywin_updater equals to the variable "currentMoney"? I cant finde the line where you defined amount = currentMoney

Comment: Whenever a signal is emitted, any slot that is connected to this signal will be called automatically where the values that are emitted with the signal are used as its arguments. In this case, `money_changed` is emitted with the new value of `self.currentMoney`. This will trigger a call to `moneywindow.moneywin_updater` where `amount` will be equal to the value that was emitted with `money_changed`, i.e. `self.currentMoney`.